# vb.net startup form shows project closed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

This might be a case of never noticed OR I have broke something

I have three projects two with multiple forms and one with only one form
Visual Studio 2019 v 16.6.2 with Frame Work 4.7.2 On Windows 7 64 bit
All the projects are WinForms with VB
I have been making a number of changes like Under Compile un-check 32 bit it is back on now
Under Application I changed framework to 4.6.1 It is back to 4.72 now

My Subs do not look to have the correct format to me please I am only 3 weeks into this IDE
I do not see the ByVal and ByRef tabs in any of my Subs in any of the Projects

```
Private Sub frmOne_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load<br/>
```

I have Shutdown Mode set to When Last Form Closes for startup form YES I tested both ways
When I say Shows Project Closed here is what I see (See Screen Shot)
All the projects run as expected
[image: Screen Shot]

I tested these lines of code on all three project it does not work and I do not understand it so it is deleted

```
Public Sub SetIcon()
    InitializeComponent()
    Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
End Sub
```

**The question is this normal behavior and I have been asleep for 3 weeks?**

**If this is not normal behavior where do I look or how do I fix this?**

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "Shows Project Closed" and your screenshot doesn't really help. Can you please explain what you expect to see and how what you do see differs from that?

Comment: `ByVal` is the default for method parameters so it can now be specified implicitly. That has been the case for several years now. If the IDE generates a method or you have pretty listing enabled, you will not see `ByVal` at all. This is much like C# has always been, where there is no keyword for passing by value and you only need a keyword in the minority of cases where you pass by reference.

Comment: Why are you calling `InializeComponent` in that method? The only pace you should be calling that method is in a constructor.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK I get that the Subs are formatted correct Looking at old code to learn has its hazards I am not use to seeing the little RED SQUARE in the screen shot that is what I mean by Show Project Closed As I said I guess I never notice it before I would swear it was always a green arrow OK I now know what  InializeComponent does and way above my pay grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That red square is simply the tool button to stop a debugging session. The *Debug* toolbar is only displayed while you're debugging, so maybe you just haven't looked at the toolbar at that time before. Have a look at the *Debug* menu in VS while you're debugging your project and while you're not to see the difference. Only options that apply to the current state are displayed.

As I mentioned in a comment, `ByVal` is the default and is now generally implicit. You can make it explicit if you want but if you have *Pretty Listing* (auto-formatting) enabled, it will be removed automatically.

`InitializeComponent` is basically the auto-generated method that creates and configures the controls and components you add in the designer. It must and should only be called in a constructor for that reason.

Comment: My use of the InitializeComponent was to show the icon in the title bar and it works as the icon is displayed BUT Form navigation no longer works SO I am sure my use was not correct As stated NOT a high priority as of now